# Rounding errors in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017

How does 6-6.0 stored as a single  integer = a negative 8.

Comment: What do you mean?  Have code?  You do mean 6 - 6.0, right?

Comment: Yes, I’m just trying to understand floating point and rounding errors.

Comment: As far as I know, the answer is that it doesn't. That's why I asked if you have code